# Generate a CSV file using PHP

Tags: php, csv

So,i want to generate CSV file using PHP from an array with customers. I've created the CSV headers('Name','Surname,'Email').

```
$customers = array(
array('id_client' => '15', 'name' => 'Michael', 'surname' => 'Andrew', 'email' => 'and@gmail.com',  'is_demo' => '1','introduction' => '0'),
array('id_client' => '16', 'name' => 'Oliver', 'surname' => 'Jake', 'email' => 'oliverj@gmail.com',  'is_demo' => '1','introduction' => '0'),
array('id_client' => '8', 'name' => 'Noah', 'surname' => 'James', 'email' => 'njam@gmail.com',  'is_demo' => '0','introduction' => '0'),);


foreach ($customers as $row =>$key) {
```

I make it an foreach but i don't know how to make a condition to this array with only name,surname,email and how have is_demo '1'.

Comment: you could use [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: You would use a "if" statement for a condition. Some more details on what you are trying to do would help.

Comment: I want to pass with fputcsv in csv file only name,surname,email and who has is_demo '1'

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$customers = array(
array('id_client' => '15', 'name' => 'Michael', 'surname' => 'Andrew', 'email' => 'and@gmail.com',  'is_demo' => '1','introduction' => '0'),
array('id_client' => '16', 'name' => 'Oliver', 'surname' => 'Jake', 'email' => 'oliverj@gmail.com',  'is_demo' => '1','introduction' => '0'),
array('id_client' => '8', 'name' => 'Noah', 'surname' => 'James', 'email' => 'njam@gmail.com',  'is_demo' => '0','introduction' => '0'),);
//
// This dir need to be writable by the web server user.
//
$fp=fopen("/full/file/path/file","w");

// this is for headding line
foreach ($customers[0] as $key => $val) {
  $csvHeadders[] = $key;
}
fputcsv($fp, $csvHeadders);

foreach ($customers as $customer) {
  if($customer['is_demo'] == '1'){
    fputcsv($fp, $customer);
  }
}
```

Comment: fputcsv($file, array('Nume', 'Surname', 'E-mail')); I've created headers and i want take from array only name,surname,email and if customers have is_demo= '1'. If i was you're last foreach i get an error Trying to access array offset on value of type int

Answer (score 0):

```
fputcsv($file, array('Name', 'Surname', 'E-mail'));


foreach ($customers as $row => $key) {
if ($key['is_demo'] === '1') {
    fputcsv($file, array($key['name'], $key['surname'], $key['email']));
} else {
    echo 'Error';
}
}
```

I just find how i take the customers by through the above conditions.